# Как указать какой юзер написал комментарий в джанго

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Хочется передать динамически имя юзера в поле комментариев, но никак не выходит, вообщем я пробовал по разному это сделать, и вот так:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    date = models.DateField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
```

и вот так:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    date = models.DateField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea
from .models import Comments


class CommentsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['name', 'text']
        widgets = {
            "name": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'value': '{{ user.get_username }}'
            }),
            "text": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Комент'
            })
        }
```

все равно не выходит занести имя пользователя после регистрации в обратную форму

P.s вот вьюха

views.py

```
def poshtwo(request):
    error = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComentiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            error = "Пожалуйста, заполните поля корректно!!!"

    return render(request, 'pepeic/cumin.html', {'djai': Comenti.objects.order_by('-datap'), 'nal': ComentiForm(), 'error': error})
```

Comment: покажи views.py а то у тебя дважды models.py

Comment: если что, то у объекта `request` есть атрибут [user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user), из него можно достать все, что нужно. И да - 2 разных варианта models.py, озаглавлены как views.py по ошибке. Но нам нужен views.py.

Answer (score 2):

Как один из вариантов:

```
    form = ComentsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.user = request.user
        comment.save()
```

или можно изначально передавать этот параметр в форму, тогда во `view`

```
    form = ComentsForm(request.POST, edit_user = request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save()
```

forms.py

```
class CommentsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['name', 'text']
        widgets = {
            "name": TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'value': '{{ user.get_username }}'
            }),
            "text": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Комент'
            })
        }
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.edit_user = kwargs.pop('edit_user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.user = self.edit_user
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Так же ты зря используешь `error = "Пожалуйста, заполните поля корректно!!!"`
После валидации формы все ошибки формы будут храниться в `form.errors` и `form.non_field_errors` их можно оттуда брать и показывать пользователю